Is it normal for a smooth curve to look like a series of lines when parameters are changing in a dynamic graph?
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[
  Evaluate@{y == -x^2 + 2*a*x + 1 - a, x == a}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -5, 
   5}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-6, 6}}, 
  Ticks -> {Range[-3, 3, 0.5], Automatic}, Frame -> False, 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], 
  Epilog -> {Red, Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}] }], {a, -3, 3}]

When parameters change in a dynamic graph, is it normal for a curve that was originally smooth to display as jagged or broken lines?

Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[
  Evaluate@{y == -x^2 + 2*a*x + 1 - a, x == a}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -5, 
   5}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-6, 6}}, 
  Ticks -> {Range[-3, 3, 0.5], Automatic}, Frame -> False, 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], 
  Epilog -> {Red, Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}] }, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {a, -3, 3}]

Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[
  Evaluate@{y == -x^2 + 2*a*x + 1 - a, x == a}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -5, 
   5}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-6, 6}}, 
  Ticks -> {Range[-3, 3, 0.5], Automatic}, Frame -> False, 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], 
  Epilog -> {Red, Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}] }, 
  PlotPoints -> ControlActive[50, 150]], {a, -3, 3}]

